# What does a `line.decode()` do in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding

In Python 3 I have to decode lines from a file to get a `str` from `bytes`. To make it compatible with Python 2 I open file in binary mode and use `.decode()` method on read lines (in Python 2 there is no `encoding` keyword for `open()` call).

```
for line in open('README.txt', 'rb'):
  # Decode to a fail-safe string for PY3
  line = line.decode('cp1252')
```

In Python 2 there is no difference between `str` and `bytes` type, so what does the `line.decode()` do?

Also this particular cases uses `cp1252` [single-char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS) encoding, and its bytes in Python 2 won't change, so what does `.decode()` do in this specific case? Is it [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP#Python) for all single-byte encodings in Python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode` on a string in Python 2 gives a unicode object.

You can check it with `type`:

```
>>> line = "ABC"
>>> type(line)
<type 'str'>
>>> line = line.decode("cp1252")
>>> type(line)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> line
u'ABC'
```

Comment: And also I found that `cp1252` is not safe - there will still be `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec` if input string contains bytes 81, 8D, 8F, 90 or 9D.

Comment: Yes, if your string contains invalid character for that encoding, a `UnicodeError` will be raised by default. You can change that behavior in your call to `decode` with the `error` keyword set to 'ignore' or 'replace'.

Comment: I just replaced `cp1252` with `cp437` - it contains all 256 bytes possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) and get the same behaviour on both Python 2 and 3 -> produce Unicode strings. The Python 3 [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) built-in is an alias for `io.open()` and `io` is also available in Python 2.

And yes, in Python 2 `bytes` is an alias for `str`; but `str` in Python 3 is not the same type! The `unicode` type from Python 2 was renamed to `str`. `str.decode()` produces `unicode` objects, in the same way that `bytes.decode()` produces a Python 3 `str`.

Comment: Thanks for `io.open()` hint - I completely missed that this thing was added in `Python 2.6` - thought that it is something from `Python 3` era.

Answer (score 0):

To start the answer for decode, we may need to know few basics

Encoding Functions: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm

Python comes with a number of codecs built-in, either implemented as C functions or with dictionaries as mapping tables. Read more below
Encoding Standards: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Decoding Functions: Is available from tutorials points similar to encode
Decoding must be done in same format which is used for encoding.

Comment: I thought that `Python 2` somehow marks the string with assumed encoding after `.decode()` call to fail with _various_ decode errors later. Now it looks like there is only one `ascii codec can't decode byte` error possible.